# Sentry in Node.JS - cannot read property captureException of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sentry

In my `express` app I initialise `Sentry` as follows.

```
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
const Tracing = require('@sentry/tracing');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);


Sentry.init({
    dsn:
        '...',
    integrations: [
        // enable HTTP calls tracing
        new Sentry.Integrations.Http({ tracing: true }),
        // enable Express.js middleware tracing
        new Tracing.Integrations.Express({ app }),
    ],

    // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    // of transactions for performance monitoring.
    // We recommend adjusting this value in production
    tracesSampleRate: 0.8,
});

app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
// TracingHandler creates a trace for every incoming request
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler());

server.listen(PORT);
```

Next, I export `Sentry` as follows from this file:

```
module.exports = {
    app,
    Sentry,
};
```

In other files, I would like to use the `captureException` method to manually report errors to `Sentry`. In these files I have:

```
const { Sentry } = require('./path/to/above/file');

Sentry.captureException(ex);
```

This throws the error to Sentry: `cannot read property captureException of undefined` which to me sounds like there's an issue with my export / import logic leading to Sentry being undefined, but I don't understand what the issue could be.

Comment: Are you sure you're requiring the right file? What is the output of `console.log(require('./path/to/above/file'))` ?

Comment: Could it be a circular dependency? I've seen issues like that in the past with Node when you reference an object from a file in another file, and vice versa and it says its undefined

Comment: Do I need to use the initialised Sentry object when I want to call `captureException` or can I just do `const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');` in those places instead?

Comment: Doing this resolves the issue. `import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';`

Comment: the comment by @Ukor should be an answer, an accepted one. Thanks!